# How to imitate cross-browser $(document).ready() behavior without JQuery

Tags: jquery, events, cross-browser, onreadystatechange, onready

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

I have a script I need to write that needs to execute on DOM ready, but I can't have dependency on JQuery as part of the script.

I want to imitate `$(document).ready()`, How can I implement this behavior in the shortest way?

Comment: Karoly was not joking.  If you really want it to function like jQuery, just use that part of the source code.

Comment: I did copy the JQuery function I seems to be the best solution, thank you I just wasn't sure

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
//do things
},false);
```

for example. Note that this might be a problem in older browsers though, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) for a list of supported browsers.

Comment: This is partial solution for some browsers only.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function() {
    // write some javascript here
    // this will be executed on page load
}
```

Comment: While this would most likely work, the code jQuery uses to bind `document.ready` is FAR more complex. If the OP is looking to imitate it directly, this will not suffice.

Comment: This is not equivalent to DOM Ready.

Answer (score -1):

You could do 2 things. On the body tag add an onload event:

```
    <body onload="myJSFunction()"></body>
```

Otherwise, you can add the functions in the bottom of the markup with:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function myFunction()</script>
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to DOM Ready.