# Get value from text field and post it in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

I have this script:

```
<script>
var dataoriginale = document.getElementById("savedataoriginale").value;
</script>
```

and this text field:

```
<input name="savedataoriginale" id="savedataoriginale" type="text" value="testtest">
```

but when I try to print the javascript var

```
<script>document.write(dataoriginale)</script>
```

I get undefined.

Why? How can I fix that?

Comment: Hard to tell because it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/GLpep/. Maybe you are trying to access the element before it exists. In that case, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196. Otherwise you have to provide a more complete example.

Comment: sorry, I posted the first javascript over the input... Usually we declare first the variable and then we work with it, not?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot access the DOM element before it exists. HTML is parsed from top to bottom.

Answer (score 3):

it's cause you have 2 conflict js session before you get the value from the input

here is work option

```
<input name="savedataoriginale" id="savedataoriginale" type="text" value="testtest">
<script>
var dataoriginale = document.getElementById("savedataoriginale").value;
document.write(dataoriginale);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably because the `<script>` is executed before the `<input>`. It happens because `document.getElementById("savedataoriginale").value` returns `undefined` when the DOM is not parsed.

To solve this, put your `<script>` tag after the `<input>` and make sure it doesn't run until the DOM is parsed. You may as well use the DOMContentLoaded event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var dataoriginale = document.getElementById("savedataoriginale").value;
  alert( dataoriginale );
},false);
```

More info:

- [How to imitate cross-browser $(document).ready() behavior without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784346/how-to-imitate-cross-browser-document-ready-behavior-without-jquery)
- [document.ready like functionality in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739128/document-ready-like-functionality-in-javascript)

PS. you don't need to have both `id` and `name` attributes on your `<input>` element. Name is deprecated. ID is enough.

Comment: `name` is deprecated? Since when? Each form element needs a name to be "successful": http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if he was actually trying to submit a <form> since there wasn't any <form> in the code snippet. But yes, if it's going to be submitted with the popular goold old "action" and Submit button it is better to provide name.